# How to call preInitialize method after host run?

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

My services are runtime generated.I need to generate controllers from generated services. PreInitialize method is working during first host run. I need it to be called from my method during runtime. How can I organize it?

Comment: aspnetboilerplate creates controller for each appservice automatically. PreInitialize() is in the module class. It's executed by aspnetboilerplate whenever a module is loaded. I guess you are on the wrong way on what you are doing. Write the target mission that you are trying to solve and we'll recommend you some other solution.

Comment: I have microservices. My microservice is responsible for connections between other services. This services must be registered in my microservice. During registration they give info about their functions(API calls) and based on this I have to generate my AppServices (runtime) for Boilerplate. The problem is that I guess we have to call PreInitialize and Initialize methods once during host run and then from registration function when AppServices will be generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AspNet Core investigates controllers on application startup. So, you can not add controller after application startup as I know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are talking about custom `IServiceProvider` implementation.

You may use your own just by changing method signature in `Startup`:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

Comment: I use this signature for ConfigureServices.

public  IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {            
           
           services.AddMvc();
           
           return services.AddAbp<HostModule>();
       }

Comment: But my question not about that services. I have classes which called AppServices in boilerplate and my classes are runtime generated.

Comment: If you implement your own `IServiceProvider` - you may implement any rules for instantiating/returning instances, including runtime class generation and moon phase detection.